# Decimal point is stripped by OdbcDataReader when connecting to an Oracle data source

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net, oracle11g, odbc

I'm using `OdbcDataReader` to connect to an Oracle database. In there I have a table with a field declared as NUMBER(8, 2). I have inserted a row with the value '8.23' into it. It displays correctly when using `SELECT * FROM <table>` in SqlDeveloper.

However, when accessing this field through ODBC from .NET using OdbcDataReader.GetDecimal() I get back a `Decimal` containing '823'. Why is this, and how do I get the correct value?

**Edit:**

If I instead use the `OracleConnection`/`OracleCommand` everything works as expected.

It also turns out that if I in my ODBC Driver configuration changes "Numeric Settings" from "Use Oracle NLS settings" to "Use US settings" the decimal point is also returned correctly. What is going on here really?

Basically I am using the code below:

```
using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM TEST", connection))
{
   using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
      }
   }
}
```

and this prints:

```
823
823
```

But running `SELECT * FROM TEST` in Oracle SQL Developer returns:

```
FLDNUM82    
---------- 
  8.23     
  8.23
```

And running `desc TEST` returns:

```
Name     Null Type        
-------- ---- ----------- 
FLDNUM82      NUMBER(8,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation and looking at the [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFXspW7/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/Odbc/OdbcDataReader@cs/1/OdbcDataReader@cs) of the `OdbcDataReader` I found that internally when retrieving a value of type decimal from an ODBC source, it actually gets it as a string from the ODBC provider, and then attempts to parse it as a decimal using the invariant culture, as indicated by the comments found in the link above:

```
// internal GetDecimal
// -------------------
// Get Value of type SQL_DECIMAL or SQL_NUMERIC
// Due to provider incompatibilities with SQL_DECIMAL or SQL_NUMERIC types we always read the value
// as SQL_C_WCHAR and convert it back to the Decimal data type
```

That means that if the data provider sends the string with a decimal point formatted in a way other than that specified by the invariant culture, the conversion will fail, or worse, produce an incorrect result. In my case the decimal point was likely sent back as a comma character, which in the US culture is a thousand-separator, meaning it was ignored in the call to `Decimal.TryParse`.

I'm not sure that the solution chosen by the authors of `OdbcDataReader` was the best here, but there may be problems in the formats that I'm not aware of. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a good way around this, other than to stay away from ODBC all-together.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Oracle ODBC Driver on Oracle Database 11gR2. Setting the [`NUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183) parameter to `US` in the ODBC connection settings solved my problem.

Possible values for `NUM` are:

- `NLS`: use Oracle NLS settings
- `MS`: use Windows regional settings
- `US`: use American settings

Comment: Thank you, Danilo! Your advice saved the day! Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

Read it as a string and convert it to decimal using [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `reader.GetString(0)` throws an exception, since the value is of type `Decimal` and not `String`. Besides, I don't actually know the type of the field so I need to use `GetValue`.

Comment: Can you use GetVaue.ToString?

Comment: Yes, and that returns '823', i.e. without the decimal point. (Updated the question with some more details)

Comment: Did you try to check whih settings are in your oracle for decimal point, maby your ODBCReader is ignoring any separators which are not culture conform, take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/web.1112/e16181/af_global.htm

Comment: See my edit. Changing the "Numeric Settings" of the Oracle ODBC driver configuration seems to yield the correct behavior in this case. But why is the OdbcDataReader not doing the correct thing in all cases here?

Comment: You are not the only on ehaving this problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6988fb71-8b89-44b5-b948-ecabf86e2fcd/odbcdatareader-problem-in-showing-decimal-fields-decimal-separator-disappear-with-db2-dsn?forum=vblanguage

Comment: If you really need to know why you may want to read the source code, search for internalGetDeciml: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFXspW7/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/Odbc/OdbcDataReader@cs/1/OdbcDataReader@cs

Comment: Okay, thanks, that piece of source code provides much of the answer. They always seem to get the data as a string, and then try to parse it as a decimal using the InvariantCulture. I guess if Oracle then does the conversion to string using another decimal point, this would cause major problems, such as in my case.